Conditions of basic formulae of thermodynamics
What is the difference between the formulas for enthalpy change:
$$\Delta H=nC_p\,\Delta T$$
and
$$\Delta H=\Delta U+\Delta(pV)$$
and is heat of reaction independent of the above formulae of enthalpy changes?

the latter is the actual definition and it simplifies to nCpdT at constant pressure

Review the guide How to ask and Asking FAQs to prevent clarification requests, objections,  downvoting or closure.

@Nightwing can you tell about the second question as well

You may find useful reviewing search results for site:stackexchange.com OR site:libretexts.org OR site:wikipedia.org   enthalpy definition temperature reaction or try similar ones.

The second formula is the general definition. It is always valid. The first formula is only used for calculating the heat necessary for heating a sample at constant pressure, without any chemistry change, and without any phase change,

The first formula is not true when there is non-PV work, like in electrochemistry.

This becomes maybe more intuitive with a Mollier diagram, where curves describe enthalpy $H$ as a function of entropy $S$ at different pressures $P$ (for each pressure a different curve).
On top of these we can also plot isolines for temperature, the temperature is equal to the slope of the curves (with constant pressure, you get $T = \frac{\Delta H}{\Delta S}$).
So, a constant pressure you can describe the enthalpy as a function of the entropy. But since the temperature is related, you can also describe it as a function of temperature.


and is heat of reaction independent of the above formulae of enthalpy changes?

Phase changes occur as a jump in the Mollier chart. And occur at a constant temperature.
The expression Δ=Δ doesn't describe that enthalpy change. It only describes the enthalpy change due to an exchange of heat.

How are you able to draw such curves ? Enthalpy can be numerically determined. But entropy cannot be directly measured like the pressure, the temperature or the volume.

@Maurice to be honest , I just made a sketch of a mollier chart, and I don't know exactly how it is experimentally determined. I guess that the entropy is derived indirectly from experiments that measure the changes in entropy by computing changes in temperature and heat. With $dS = T^{-1} dU$ you can compute $$\Delta S = \int_{U_1}^{U_2} T(U)^{-1} dU$$ This gives a way to determine relative entropy, but how they determine the absolute values, I don't know. Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/42066/is-there-a-way-to-experimentally-measure-entropy

Temperature measurements are similarly having a difficulty in deriving the absolute zero.
